# Share firebase function config between developers

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

I'm storing API keys in firebase functions config. Is it possible to share this config securely between developers?

Current problem is a developer fetches the Origin from Github, but does not receive the functions config so has to manually set all of the config variables before they can test their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to share this configuration on any repo. Once you change this config with a developer who has access to the project, other developers can see these new config changes if they have enough permission for the project. you can check the current config using

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

you can reas more about [this here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)

Comment: Ah I thought the config was local and used when the functions are built and deployed. That's great if they're stored in Firebase so anyone get them in that way :)